# Решение “ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away" в цикличных программах

Tags: python, mysql, mysqlconnector

Предоставляю **решение** схожих проблем с той, с которой лично столкнулся недавно:

Бот Телеграм связан с MySQL базой пользователей, подключение к которой производилось лишь в начале кода (при запуске) из-за чего через некоторое время (около 10 часов) соединение обрывалось и бот выкидывал ошибки, т.к. не получал информацию о пользователе.

Я использую фреймворк `mysql-connector` и это решение состоит в использовании **класса** для обработки запросов к базе, который можно увидеть ниже с примерами использования.

Answer (score 0):

**Сам класс**:

```
import logging

import mysql.connector

class DB():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="host",
            user="user",
            passwd="password",
            database="name"
        )
        try:
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

    def execute(self, query, data=None, ret1=False):
        try:
            if not self.conn:
                self.__init__()
            else:
                if data:
                    self.cursor.execute(query, data)
                else:
                    self.cursor.execute(query)

                if 'INSERT' in query or 'UPDATE' in query or 'DELETE' in query or 'DROP' in query:
                    self.conn.commit()

                if ret1:
                    return self.cursor.fetchone()
                else:
                    return self.cursor.fetchall()

        except:
            logging.error('end', exc_info=True)
            return 'error'
```

**Пример таблицы**:

[image: Пример таблицы]

**Структура запроса**:

```
res = DB().execute(запрос, защищённые данные) # fetchall
res = DB().execute(запрос, защищённые данные, True) # fetchone
```

**Примеры использования**:

```
> DB().execute("CREATE TABLE users (r_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, id INT UNIQUE, name VARCHAR(255), role INT NULL DEFAULT 3)")
> DB().execute("INSERT INTO users (id, name, role) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (65453, "Mike", 1,))
> res = DB().execute(f"SELECT * FROM users")
res = [(1, 146, "Nick", 3,), (2, 155, "John", 1,), (3, 678, "Michelle", 2,), (4, 65453, "Mike", 1,)]
> res = DB().execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = %s", ("John",), ret1=True)
res = (2, 155, "John", 1,)
```

Если есть какие-то предложения по оптимизации, обязательно пишите!

Comment: Перенесите все это в вопрос, кнопка `править`. Это же не является ответов, а дополнением к вопросу?

Comment: Это моё же решение данной проблемы, вопроса тут нет, просто делюсь информацией, которую не смог найти.

Comment: Ок, ошибся, но в вопросе не было кода, это помогло бы найти проблему. А ответ нужно было начинать с того, что проблема была решена после реализации вспомогательного класса для работы с бд. Т.е. эта тема начинается с того, что у вас проблема, а по факту вы похвастались своим решением, которое не вызывает проблем :)

Comment: Спасибо, согласен - исправил!