# MySQL server has gone away telegram bot python

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot, telebot

Очень нужна помощь с ботом на питоне, который день ломаю голову:)

```
def start(message):
DB.sql.execute("SELECT * FROM teleusers WHERE user_id = %s", (message.chat.id,))
if DB.sql.fetchone() == None:
    DB.sql.execute("INSERT INTO teleusers VALUES (NULL, %s, %s ,%s, %s, NULL, CURTIME())", (message.chat.id, message.chat.first_name, message.chat.last_name, message.chat.username))
    DB.db.commit()
    DB.db.close()
greet = 'Привет,' + ' ' + message.chat.first_name + ' ' + '! блаблабла'
return greet
```

в двух словах, если база пустая, при попытке у бота вызвать /start - бот падает с ошибкой

```
2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'remote.mysql.tools:3306', system error: 10038 An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

при этом, запись добавляется в базу!!! однако, если запись уже в базе есть и select отрабатывает - никаких ошибок вроде бы не наблюдается. В то же время, если из кода убрать закрытие соединения с БД - все чудесно отрабатывает на пустой базе, селектит, пишет значения, делает выборку в другой функции, НО....если не закрывать оставить открытым соединение и оставить бота на какое то время, то вновь падение бота с ошибкой

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
```

к с этим бороться? не судите строго, я только учусь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128555/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%85?rq=1
решил этим способом